# Is it possible to write a more accurate Close message?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In a recent [question closure](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/407080/112436), the reason box displayed was:

> Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests.

I voted to reopen because it seemed to me that OP did include information on how the word would be used.

MetaEd responded:

> "Information on how it will be used" is actually intended to mean not just giving a sample sentence but actually providing all the information on how it will be used that's called for by the linked tag wiki, including research results, part of speech, register, acceptance criteria, etc. In fact, if you see a way to improve on how that close reason is written, you might throw a suggestion onto meta. The mod team can and occasionally does edit the close reasons.

**Can this close message be improved?**

Comment: Can you add a link to the question?

Comment: @curiousdannii - Thanks, I hadn't noticed my link was broken.

Comment: Please submit your own proposed close reason in an answer box, so that people voting on it can vote freely without tainting your question's premise. I'm upvoting your question, but not necessarily your proposed draft.

Comment: Clearly separating question and answer as @NVZ suggests also means that others can also suggest improvements which can be voted on. Here's [an example of mine](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/should-we-amend-the-help-text-to-expand-on-proof-reading) (although no-one else had any other ideas in that case).

Comment: Yes, @AndrewLeach has shown a good example of how the community works together to bring change. If needed, this meta may be "featured" to bring in more pairs of eyes. But before that, please separate your draft from the question.

Comment: I wonder what OP and you'd like to achieve by asking and trying to reopen this meaningless and unanswerable question. It's a good idea to suggest we rewrite the close reason.

Comment: @Rathony - I only mentioned that question so folks would understand where the Meta question came from.  That question in itself is not very important to me.  The point was that the OP included a sample sentence, so I was confused why various people voted to close.

Comment: @aparente001 The reason various people voted to close it was they couldn't find any reason why they should not vote to close the crap. Please don't take such a lousy question as an example. This site is ELU.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a first stab at a revision:

> For word, phrase, idiom or expression requests, please include a sample sentence, the part of speech and register desired, acceptance criteria, and what you've considered but rejected.

Comment: "one or more sample sentences"?

Comment: Here's how I summarized the word request and phrase request tag wikis earlier today. Maybe this will give you some ideas as you formulate your proposal. "Please describe exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase--generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for."

Comment: @MetaEd - Should the specific proposals go in a different question?  This is getting a little muddled for me.  Q1: Is it possible to improve the message?  Votes indicate yes/no.  Q2: What should the new message be?  Well, frankly, I'm not sure I want to get deeply involve in the revision process, partly because I'm not going to have time to work much on it this week, and partly because this is ELU so I imagine people here will have strong opinions about wording.

Comment: I'm just flinging food for thought, not suggesting a revision.

Answer (score -1):

> "Please show us the context in which you want to use the word or phrase--a sample sentence is often helpful; specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers; share the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.); list words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why; and provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you're looking for."
>
> - [modified from MetaEd ♦'s suggestion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/is-it-possible-to-write-a-more-accurate-close-message#comment-44387)

Comment: I'd rather see semicolons so it's clear that all the things listed are strongly encouraged. // How about: Please show us the context in which you want to use the word or phrase--a sample sentence is often helpful.

Comment: @aparente001 feel free to change it. It's a community wiki..

Comment: @MetaEd - Please roll back if the edits don't fit with your vision.

Comment: Are sample sentences only encouraged, or are they actually required, as per the single-word-request tag description?

Comment: @1006a what do you think? If you reckon they should, add an answer and let everyone choose :)